# why is css white background for this div not actually white but transparent?

Tags: css, background, transparent

http://jsfiddle.net/QjF4d/

I have a `div.rating_bar` which is superimposed on over a `div.artist`.  The `.rating bar` has a background color of white but it doesn't display as white, instead it's just transparent.  How come?

Edit: z-index of elements defined lower in the source code are greater than that of elements defined higher in the source.  Once I moved the .rating bar lower in the source, I could see the white background as it was now sitting on top of the semi-transparent div, rather than under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any `z-index` in your css, so I don't know why you presume who is on top of what. In short, white is white, it's just that rating_bar div ended up below artist one.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the `div.rating_bar` a higher `z-index` then the `div.artist` - The `:hover` boxes will need higher `z-index` then `div.rating_bar`